# create-react-app not working when added to android home screen

Tags: android, reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app, react-router-v4

I got an app created with react material-ui, react-router v4 and using featherjs as backend. If I visit from the browser, the data loads and render but when I add it to my smartphone's home screen and view it. It doesn't load any data or render.

What's the problem? How can I debug this?

Comment: Are you using react router? I have the issue where it is not opening the router configured for "/"

Comment: didnt work with iPhone either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 4 months old, but i figured other people like me would benefit from an answer to the question. I found an article online : https://ayastreb.me/react-router-in-home-screen-pwa/

The idea is that you need to use hash based navigation for the router when your app starts from the homescreen as a standalone app (otherwise router doesn't fire up and your app is doing nothing). You can detect the case on lauch and switch to a hash based navigation - see the article.